# ColorAnimation for TemplateBinding Background Property on DataTrigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, datatrigger

I have a button with a `Template`, like below,

```
<Button>            
        <Button.Style>                        
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">                            
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                <Path Stretch="Fill" Width="25" Height="25" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" >
                                   <Path.Data>
                                      <RectangleGeometry Rect="10,10 200,140"/>
                                   </Path.Data>
                                </Path>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

I am trying to animate the `Background` on a `DataTrigger` in `Style` like below,

```
 <Style.Triggers>
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsNoteOpen}" Value="true">
         <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
              <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Sb1">
                  <BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                      <Storyboard>
                         <ColorAnimation 
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                             From="White" To="Red" Duration="0:00:0.3" AutoReverse="True"/>
                       </Storyboard>
                   </BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
               </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
          <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
              <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Sb1"/>
          </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
```

But its not getting animated on the `DataTrigger`. any help

Comment: Change `(Button.Background)` to `(Path.Fill)`, remove the `From` and I'm not sure you want the AutoReverse

Comment: Ok then, I'll take an actual look instead of skimming (bad habit of mine) and `RepeatBehavior` is to repeat the behavior. AutoReverse would negate itself, aka white to red then red to white. Anyway one sec let me finish what I'm currently working on and swing back.

Comment: Solution is simple, place the `DataTrigger` inside of the `ControlTemplate` i.e. `<ControlTemplate>.<Triggers>`. HTH

Comment: I haven't got code with me but I did exactly same thing at work, I'll post an update once I have access to my code.

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MainTilesButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCF5F5F5"/><!--This is background colour with opcaity defined-->
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Style="{StaticResource part_ButtonBorder}">
                        <Border.RenderTransform>
                            <RotateTransform/>
                        </Border.RenderTransform>
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            TextBlock.FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold"
                            TextBlock.TextAlignment="Justify" 
                            TextBlock.FontSize="26.667"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!--<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" To="-360" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>-->
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="10" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation 
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                             From="White" To="ForestGreen" Duration="0:00:0.3" AutoReverse="True"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="20" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <!--<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="20" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>-->
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I have included your `Storyboard` in there and tested it. I can confirm that this is working on my PC.
BTW this is the part_ButtonBorder:

```
<Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="part_ButtonBorder">
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="30"/>
</Style>
```

**EDIT**
I have tried using path in my xaml and it works as expected, the path fill is set to the background of the button, reason why you might not see it is because paths colour is going to be the same as the background of the button.
Here is code snippet with the path included, NOTE that the path has stroke defined so you can see the outline of it.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MainTilesButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCF5F5F5"/>
    <!--This is background colour with opcaity defined-->
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Style="{StaticResource part_ButtonBorder}">
                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            TextBlock.FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold"
                            TextBlock.TextAlignment="Justify" 
                            TextBlock.FontSize="26.667"/>
                        <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Data="m 193.2 112.7 -0.3 0.3 -0.6 0 -0.6 -0.3 -2.1 -2.1 -0.3 0 c -1.5 1.5 -3.5 2.6 -7.1 2.6 -4.1 0 -6.8 -2.6 -6.8 -6.2 0 -3.2 2.1 -5 4.4 -5.9 l 0 -0.3 c -0.9 -0.9 -2.1 -2.4 -2.1 -4.4 0 -2.1 1.2 -4.4 4.7 -4.4 3.2 0 4.4 2.4 4.4 4.1 0 3.2 -2.1 4.4 -3.8 5.3 l 0 0.3 5.9 5.9 0.3 0 c 0.6 -1.2 0.9 -2.9 0.9 -5.9 l 0.3 -0.3 1.2 0 0.3 0.3 c 0 3.5 -0.6 5.6 -1.5 7.1 l 0 0.3 2.6 2.6 0 1 z m -5 -3.6 -6.8 -6.8 -0.3 0 c -2.6 0.9 -3.8 2.4 -3.8 4.7 0 2.6 1.8 4.7 5 4.7 2.6 0 4.7 -0.9 5.9 -2.4 l 0 -0.2 z m -5.6 -15.6 c -2.1 0 -2.9 1.2 -2.9 2.9 0 1.5 0.6 2.4 2.1 3.8 l 0.6 0 c 1.8 -0.9 2.9 -1.8 2.9 -3.8 -0.1 -1.4 -0.7 -2.9 -2.7 -2.9 z"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <!--<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" To="-360" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>-->
                                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="10" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                <ColorAnimation 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                     From="White" To="ForestGreen" Duration="0:00:0.3" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="20" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <!--<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="20" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>-->
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

One more thing to look out for is the Path it self, I have noticed the one that I am using is positioned very low so when you want to see it you need to stretch the Window a little so you can see it.

Comment: I think the issue lies within the `TemplateBinding`, Have you tried combining `RelativeSource` with `(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't tag you @AbinMathew.

Comment: @AbinMathew What do you mean? I have tested this code and it works on my machine. Are you using this inside of a template?

Comment: @AbinMathew OK, have you tried using different Trigger in your Style to find out if it is working for mouse events?

Comment: @AbinMathew Well then, you could use my solution and adapt it to your scenario.

Comment: Well you can compare my solution to yours and step by step try to use some parts. When you find the part that is making your code working you have found the Root Cause of your problem, from there you can do research on msdn to find out how microsoft has put WPF together. HTH